# XHR GET Request params object

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

So I'm trying to figure out how to XHR with a GET request that will format a the params like this:

`https:://api.com/endpoint?id=userId&list=list1%5D=1&list=list2%5D=1`

I am building an object called lists that looks like

```
const lists = {
   'list1' : 1,
   'list2': :1
}
```

I know this works with $.ajax like so:

```
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://api.com/endpoint',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        "type": "POST",
        "id": userId,
        "lists": lists
      }
    })
```

But I need to do this with vanilla JS. I've tried the following:

```
    const params = `type=POST&id=${userId}&lists=${lists}`
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

    xhr.open('GET', `https://api.com/endpoint${params}`);

    xhr.send(encodeURI(params))
```

That just tries to hit: 
`https://api.com/endpoint&type=POST&id=userId&lists=[object%20Object]`

So my main thing is to try and get the URL to format the lists param to 
`&list=list1%5D=1&list=list2%5D=1`

I hope that makes sense!

Cheers

Comment: It's more simple when sending objects using the POST method.

Comment: `&list=list1%5D=1&list=list2%5D=1` is wrong url-encoding